# html/css/javascript project modularization best practices

Tags: javascript, html, css

Compared with Java/C#/C/C++ projects, we often see web frontend projects (html/css/javascript) are too complex to read and maintain. So, can we summarize some best practices for web frontend projects? The goal is readability, modularization, easy to maintain.

Comment: Some good comments below. I would also like to add that the book "High Performance Web Sites" provides some really good best practice knowledge for Front End development - mostly deals with performance tips, but still valuable read. Thought you might enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Accomplishing this takes a mix of good patterns and knowing what fights not to fight.

1. CSS is best if it's factored out, efficient, and cleanly formatted.  No overthinking necessary here, CSS is a beautiful language, I like to keep it simple.  For example see my answer here: [MVC 3, CSS, Razor and Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265756/mvc-3-css-razor-and-visual-studio-2010/5383482#5383482)
2. Javascript can definitely be organized by using some kind of object based pattern: http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/.  I use something close to "Custom Objects" from that link.  With YUI we have built in namespaces, with jQuery we can add them: [Is it possible to create a namespace in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527089/is-it-possible-to-create-a-namespace-in-jquery).  As far as separating out content, separate objects and related functionality in their own javascript files and include them on the pages where they're needed.  For optimization, you can compile all the scripts on any page down into one script.  YUI 3 has a great dependency loading mechanism - use that.  For jQuery, you can use one of the many dependency loaders: [Javascript loaders with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640060/javascript-loaders-with-jquery/5641670#5641670)
3. As far as HTML, I think MVC is the most popular patter these days.  Using any modern mvc framework will lay things out for you well.  (Ex. rails, any java ones, asp.net mvc, pylons, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for now, web development has many approaches and there's no standard way of doing things.

By the way, since JavaScript doesn't support some OOP features like actual classes or namespacing, but prototyping, you need to know that this isn't a good start for crearting good and large moduralized front-end Web projects.

Although there're limitations, you can use prototyping in order to leverage some kind of pseudo-OOP design. That's you can create a component-oriented user interface based on inheritance of some abstract hierarchy defining common behaviors and visualizations.

Keeping in mind one of most important points in any modern development is reuse and scalability, I think using pseudo-OOP with prototyping should be fine to avoid bad practices and enforce maintainibility, readability and moduralization.

For example, you can simulate namespacing with prototypes. This is achieved by creating anonymous objects where their members are anonymous functions acting as getters (properties) where their return type is the prototype of some actual "class" - there're other ways to achieve this same result -:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jsnamespaces.aspx

Or you can simulate polymorphism:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/edujini_007_JavaScript_OO.aspx

I could add more references, but I believe you got it: it's more like trying to export actual OOP approaches to JavaScript and use same design patterns that have been in the ground for a lot of years!

Another point should be you can get this moduralization by extending existing JavaScript frameworks like jQuery, Prototype, MooTools, Microsoft AJAX (this is a good start because it has many built-in OOP features like namespaces, inheritance, polymorphism...).